# Discrete-Time Fourier Transform of a non-absolutely-summable sequence

Tags: fourier-analysis

The absolute summability of a sequence $x(n)$ is a sufficient---but not necessary---condition for the existence of its Discrete-Time Fourier Transform . Without using distributions, could anybody provide an example of a non-absolutely-summable sequence $x(n)$ for which the DTFT exists?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the meaning of DTFT ?

Comment: DTFT: Discrete-Time Fourier Transform.  have edited the post to expand the acronym.